# make iframe clickable link

Tags: html, css, iframe, clickable

What i'm trying to do, is to make the iframe clickable
I found this code that can make this work:

```
div.iframe-link {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 115%;
  height: 516px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
a.iframe-link {
  text-decoration:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:105%;
  height:516px;
}
```

This is the iframe:

```
<div class="iframe-link">
<iframe src="http://bidra.no/integrer/7182e5a4-612a-49fc-aecb-e7934706a777" width="105%" height="516" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless">
</iframe> 
<a class="iframe-link" href="http://bidra.no/kampanje/st%C3%B8tt-siops-info-og-ressurssenter-for-veteraner/7182e5a4-612a-49fc-aecb-e7934706a777" target="_blank"> &nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

My friend can't get it to work in Firefox

It's working for me on firefox, chrome and safari.

Comment: Sounds like your friend has some browser plugin/extension that prevents clickjacking or simitar attacks.

Comment: If this is actually working somewhere, set a high z-index to a.iframe-link

Comment: Does it matter how high i set the z-index?

Comment: It needs to be higher than the iframe so greater than 1. I usually exaggerate the number to make sure it works.